# Basic array comparison algorithm

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, collections

I'm trying to follow the [steps found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) on comparing two arrays, and knowing when to create a new object, but I just don't understand how it works:

> You end up with two sorted arrays—one with the employee IDs passed
>   into the fetch request, and one with the managed objects that matched
>   them. To process them, you walk the sorted lists following these
>   steps:

```
Get the next ID and Employee. If the ID doesn't match the Employee ID, create a new Employee for that ID.
Get the next Employee: if the IDs match, move to the next ID and Employee.
```

> Regardless of how many IDs you pass in, you only execute a single
>   fetch, and the rest is just walking the result set.

Basically what's happening is I have an array of object ids from an external source, and the client system only has a subset of the objects represented by these ids. I need to figure out which objects I already have, and if I don't have them, create them, one by one.

I don't understand how this works. I'm having trouble translating this to code:

```
for (int i =0;i<ids.count;i++) {
    currentId = [ids objectAtIndex:i];
    currentObject = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

    if(currentObject.id != currentId) {
        //create new object
    }

    //"get the next employee"
    //uh what?
    nextEmployee = [objects objectAtIndex:i+1]; //?
    if(nextEmployee.id == currentId) {
        //"move on to the next id"
        continue;
    }
}
```

I don't see how that would work? What am I missing?

Comment: What error are you getting? What's not working?

Comment: I'm just not understanding how to map it into code. I'm pretty sure my implementation above is incorrect, no? I just don't understand how the whole algorithm works..

Comment: Ok. See my below implementation of the algorithm

Comment: If you have any questions about my code, just ask it in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//Employee.h
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger ID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

//Employee.m
@synthesize ID, name;



//Place where you put algorithm
#import "Employee.h"
------------------------
NSMutableArray *employeeIDs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123], [NSNumber numberWithInt:456], [NSNumber numberWithInt:789], nil];

//Creates employee objects
Employee *employee1 = [[Employee alloc] init];
employee1.ID = 123;
employee1.name = @"John Smith";

Employee *employee2 = [[Employee alloc] init];
employee2.ID = 456;
employee2.name = @"Bob Day";

Employee *employee3 = [[Employee alloc] init];
employee3.ID = 789;
employee3.name = @"Steve Jobs";

NSMutableArray *employeesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:employee1, employee2, employee3, nil];

for (int index = 0; index <= [employeeIDs count]; index++) {

    for(id currentEmployee in employeesArray){

        if(currentEmployee.ID != currentID){

            Employee *newEmployee = [[Employee alloc] init];
            newEmployee.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Employee Name"];
            newEmployee.ID = 384;

            [employeeIDs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:newEmployee.ID]];
            [employees addObject:newEmployee.name];

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wait, is this the same way as Apple was saying, or is this another implementation?

Comment: @mohabitar This is the way that Apple was saying. First, it iterates through the employee ID's and checks if that ID matches any of the employees' ID. If it does, it goes on to the next ID. If it does not match, it creates a new employee.

Comment: I don't see how this can work. This iterates through the `employeesArray` every time for each `employeeID`, so the `if (currentEmployee.ID != currentID)` condition is going to be true many times.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question after looking at the same example in the Core Data Programming Guide.

This is my solution:

The key is that you are walking 2 arrays separately, one array contains all the employeeId strings that need to exist in Core Data, and the other contains Employee objects that already exist in Core Data, filtered by the employeeId strings. Both arrays have been sorted.

So lets say we have the sorted employeeIds array containing strings:

```
@"10",@"11",@"12",@"15",@"20"
```

And that we have a matchingEmployees array containing 2 Employee objects with employeeId 10 and 15.

We need to create new Employee objects for employees with employeeIDs 11,12 and 20, while potentially updating the attributes of employees 10 and 15 . So:

```
int i = 0; // employeeIds array index
int j = 0; // matchingEmployees array index

while ((i < [employeeIds count]) && (j <= [matchingEmployees count])){

  NSString *employeeId = [employeeIds objectAtIndex:i];

  Employee *employee = nil;

  if ([matchingEmployees count]!=0)
      employee = [matchingEmployees objectAtIndex:j];

  if (![employeeId isEqualToString:employee.employeeId]){

      employee = //Insert new Employee entity into context
      employee.employeeId = employeeId;

      //Set any attributes for employee that do not change
  }
  else {
      //We matched employeeId to Employee so the next iteration
      //of this loop should check the next Employee object
      j++; 
  }

  //Set any attributes for employee that change with each update

  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a linear search in your objects array to check if you can find it, perhaps something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.count; i++) {
    bool found = NO;
    currentId = [ids objectAtIndex:i];

    // We need to traverse the whole array to check if we can find the objectID somewhere...
    for(int j = 0; j < objects.count; j++) {
        currentObject = [objects objectAtIndex:j];

        if (currentId == currentObject) {
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        // Create the new object
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 arrays, with no specific orders (I suppose), so binary search won't be useful. Maybe I don't have all the infos about your problem, but from what I see, you'll need 2 `for` loop to traverse the second one, making it O(n^2)...

Comment: Ya but doesn't Apple's approach have just one for loop?

Comment: @mohabitar The Apple approach explicitly has one loop, but beneath the surface there is another array that loops through **every** employee to check if the ID in matches any of them

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
NSArray *wholeList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"employee1", @"employee2", @"employee3", @"employee4", @"employee5",@"employee6", nil];
NSArray *partialList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"employee2", @"employee13", @"employee7", nil];

for (id employeeID in partialList)  //get one employee from the partialList
{
    if (![wholeList containsObject:employeeID])  //check to see if it is in the wholeList
    {
        NSLog(@"This employee is not in the wholeList: %@", employeeID);
        // do create new employee object for this employeeID, whatever...
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't as efficient as the way apple is recommending. You have a for loop with O(n) and then [list containsObject:] which I think is O(n) too. The way from above is more efficient, I just don't know how to implement it