# Best practice in recreating CoreData entities with actual data retrieved from the server

Tags: ios, core-data, afnetworking

Purpose: I have to create entities from files.

So entities represent my data model in CoreData and files have all information for this entities.

All files I get from Internet. For this I use AFNetworking framework.

How I get files (algorithm):

1. Request plist file. Plist file has values to other urls that I have to download.
2. When plist was downloaded to my Documents directory on device. I parse it.
3. When I parse plist I grab url from each item from NSDictionary that represent this plist.
4. Then I request zip files from this urls.
5. After zip files were downloaded I unzip them and go to the next step.
6. Parse unzipped files and create data model.

It is my problem. I have version of file that stored locally and that stored on the server and when version on the server changed I need to reload my data model with actual data. The bad way it is load all data from server again next delete all entities in storage and make new entities from new data. But it is not professional way at first and second it is an additional burden on the traffic, because if I have just one entity that I need to reload why I have to reload other entities that are in the actual state. So maybe someone knows best practice with this question. Of course I can create my solution and it will work, but I want to see how people solve this problem and figure out with the differences in my solution and in the other solutions also.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial. You simply keep an attribute with the time stamp of the last update and just request the changed and new entities from your server. Then you insert, update or delete as appropriate.

Comment: Yes this is really trivial, but maybe someone knows link with solutions this problem. I mean how it looks in code, where described algorithm and some OOP features or patterns that help to create more clean system for understanding code. Of course I can compare two files and load it, but I want to see way how to create more simple in the code. Thanks for response in any case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about find-or-create. Depending on the size of the data set and your performance requirements you can do this a couple of ways:

The first way is to fetch your existing Core Data objects and store them in an a dictionary with a unique attribute of the entity serving as the key. Then when you download the new data you can take this key for each parsed object and check your dictionary to find (and optionally update) any existing object, or create a new one:

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = //Fetch the existing objects;    

NSMutableDictionary *existingObjects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (MyClass *object in fetchedObjects)
    [existingObjects setObject:object forKey:object.uniqueKey];

//Now iterate through the new data (using JSON as example here)

NSDictionary *downloadedItems = //Download data and serialise into JSON

for (NSDictionary *item in downloadedItems){

    NSString *uniqueValue = [item valueForKey:@"uniqueKey"];

    MyClass *object = [existingObjects objectForKey:uniqueValue];

    if (object==nil){

       object = //Insert new MyClass entity into MOC
       object.uniqueKey = uniqueValue;

       //Set any other values you only need to set once
    }

    //Set any values you may need to update every time
    //This would be where to check a modified date attribute
}
```

The second way is more sophisticated, and involves less memory overhead. It's described in the Efficiently Importing Data section of the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html.).

The guide gives a good start but doesn't offer a complete solution; I attempted my own in an answer here: [Basic array comparison algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12591745/228981)